# Pygames math.Vector2( ) errors

Tags: pygame, runtime-error, game-physics

Im converting my small physics test code in pygame from using pairs of variables to describe position, velocity and acceleration into math.Vector2()'s. The reason being is obvious since there are a whole lot of methods relating to the Vector2 that make it easy to find the length, normalize, cross product so on and so forth.

In the pygame docs it also has a whole bunch of numerical operations it supports like vec*number, vec*=vec etc. However my issue has arisen when I start to use the vec+=vec or vec*=vec. I am getting this kind of error...

"malloc: *** error for object 0x7fb4a1ec31a0: pointer being freed was not allocated"

If I comment out all those operations the code runs fine without animation of course. Is there a bug with Vector2() or am I just utilising it wrong?

```
import pygame, math, random

pygame.init() 

class Circle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, screen):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.screen = screen
        self.position =  pygame.math.Vector2(random.randrange(20,self.screen.get_width()), self.screen.get_height()/3)
        self.velocity = pygame.math.Vector2(0.0, 0.0)
        self.acceleration = pygame.math.Vector2(0.0, 0.1)
        self.netForce =  pygame.math.Vector2(0.0, 0.0)
        self.x = random.randrange(20,self.screen.get_width())
        self.y = self.screen.get_height()/2
        self.radius = random.randrange(5,30)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((self.radius*2,self.radius*2))
        self.image.set_colorkey((0,0,0))
        self.image.set_alpha(120)
        self.mass = self.radius/15.0
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, (175,255,0), (self.radius,self.radius), self.radius)
        self.image = self.image.convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = self.position

    def update(self):
        self.calcPos()
        self.checkBounds()
        self.rect.center = self.position
        self.netForce *= 0.0


    def calcPos(self): 
        self.acceleration = self.netForce
        self.velocity += self.acceleration
        self.position += self.velocity 


    def applyForce(self, force):
        force /self.mass
        self.netForce += force

    def checkBounds(self):
        if self.position[1] > self.screen.get_height():
            self.acceleration[1] *= -1.0
            self.position[1] = self.screen.get_height()
        if self.position[0] > self.screen.get_width(): 
            self.acceleration[0] *= -1.0
            self.position[0] = self.screen.get_width()
        if self.position[1] < 0: 
            self.acceleration[1] *= -1.0
        if self.position[0] < 0: 
            self.acceleration[0] *= -1.0

def main():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,400))
    background = pygame.Surface((screen.get_size()))
    background.fill((150,150,150)) 
    background = background.convert()

    circleGRP = pygame.sprite.Group() #Add balls
    for x in range(10):
        circleGRP.add(Circle(screen))

    wind = pygame.math.Vector2(1.0, 0)
    gravity = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 1.0)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    mainLoop = True

    while mainLoop: 
        clock.tick(30) #Clock
        for event in pygame.event.get(): #Key events
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                mainLoop = False
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    mainLoop = False
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: #Add wind
                if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
                    for circle in circleGRP:
                        circle.applyForce(wind)

 #----------------------------------------------------------------------------                   
        for circle in circleGRP: #Add gravity
            gravity = gravity * circle.mass
            circle.applyForce(gravity)
            #pass 

            #circleX = circle.dx * -1 #Add drag
            #circleY = circle.dy * -1
            #drag = (circleX/80* circle.mass* (circle.radius/5), circleY/80* circle.mass* (circle.radius/5))
            #circle.applyForce(drag)

 #----------------------------------------------------------------------------    
        circleGRP.update()  
        screen.blit(background, (0,0))
        circleGRP.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: It says the pygame.math module is experimental so it's possible.

Comment: Yes though that was a while ago now, Im hoping some work has been done on this since considering the amount of pygames being released in beta over the years.

Comment: It says that it's new in v 1.10 which I think is the newest version? -- You could use `numpy` for 2d vectors.

Comment: Im using Pygame 1.9.2 not sure how long its been since 1.10 only just started using it to be honest. I had a go at installing numpy but Im not the best at this stuff and it failed. Guess Ill keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use the `Vec2d` class that is given [here](http://pygame.org/wiki/2DVectorClass).

It has operator overloading (can use with tuples or lists), uses slots for perforance, is picklable, implements list interface (so it's compatible with pygame functions), has a fair bit of high level vector operators (for performance and readability) and has unit tests built in.

I have worked with it in simulations and physics testings, and it provides all that you need.